# Modulus of continuity and circle endomorphism

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, change-of-variable

I'm reading a paper and I can't understand this variable change
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}f\left(\frac{t}{C\lambda^{x}}\right)dx = \frac{1}{\log{\lambda}}\int_{0}^{\frac{t}{C\lambda}}\frac{f(y)}{y}dy
$$
I would be very grateful if someone can help me in any way.

edit: $\lambda > 1, t>0$ and $C> 0$.

Comment: They made a mistake in the upper bound. $y = \frac{t}{C\lambda^x} \implies \frac{t}{C\lambda^0} = \frac{t}{C} \neq \frac{t}{C\lambda}$ (the implicit assumption here being $\lambda > 1$ for the lower bound to be true)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether your equation is entirely correct. In fact, for $C = t = 1, \lambda = 2$ and $f = \mathrm{id}$ WolframAlpha calculates the [right hand side](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20from%200%20to%20infinity%20of%20%281%2F2%5Ex%29dx%20) as approximately $1.4$ but the [left hand side](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%20%2F%20%282log%202%29) as approximately $0.7$.

A only slightly different result is obtained by using substitution with the inverse function of $\varphi: x \mapsto {t \over {C \lambda^x}}$ which is $$\varphi^{-1}: y \mapsto - \frac{\log(yC) - \log(t)}{\log \lambda}$$ with $$(\varphi^{-1})': y \mapsto - \frac{1}{\log \lambda} \frac{1}{yC} \cdot C = - \frac{1}{y \cdot \log \lambda}.$$  Then the substitution formula gives us
$$ \int_0^\infty f\left(\frac{t}{C \lambda^x}\right) dx = \int_{\varphi(0)}^{\varphi(\infty)} f(y) \cdot (\varphi^{-1})'(y) dy = \int_0^{\frac{t}{C}} \frac{f(y)}{y \log \lambda} dy, $$
where I assumed that $| \lambda | > 1$ which gives $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \varphi(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{t}{C \lambda^x} = 0$.

Comment: I agree with you. I will take $f$ different of identity map.